# Wifi P2P sending data failed on phones with Android 8

Tags: android-studio, sockets

I would like to send data with a Wifi P2p Connection between two phones. This works quite well with an Android Version below 8 (Oreo), but the program stops on android 8 when I try to send something. I checked the code multiple times, but I could not find something wrong.

```
package com.example.wificonnectiontry2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    private EditText writeMsg;

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    private String[] deviceNameArray;
    private WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;

    private static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;

    ServerClass serverClass;
    ClientClass clientClass;
    SendReceive sendReceive;

    private boolean gpsGoOn = false;
    private boolean connected = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String tempMsg = new String(readBuff, 0, msg.arg1);
                    read_msg_box.setText(tempMsg);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    private void exqListener() {
    btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                btnOnOff.setText("Wifi On");
            }else{
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                btnOnOff.setText("Wifi Off");
            }
        }
    });

    btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            discoverPeers();
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final WifiP2pDevice device = deviceArray[position];
            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;

            mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "+device.deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(connected) {
                String msg = writeMsg.getText().toString();
                sendReceive.write(msg.getBytes());
            }
        }
    });
    }

    private void discoverPeers(){
        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Started");
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                    LocationManager L = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (!L.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please activate GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        gpsGoOn = true;
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Starting Failed");
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialWork() {
    btnOnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onOff);
    btnDiscover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discover);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
    read_msg_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
    connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
    writeMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

    wifiManager =(WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

    mReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_DISCOVERY_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    }

    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)){
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index = 0;

                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()){
                    deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                    deviceArray[index] = device;
                    index++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceNameArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            if(peers.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener connectionInfoListener = new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {
            final InetAddress groupOwner = info.groupOwnerAddress;

            if(info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner){
                connectionStatus.setText("Host");
                serverClass = new ServerClass();
                serverClass.start();
            }else{
                connectionStatus.setText("Client");
                clientClass = new ClientClass(groupOwner);
                clientClass.start();
            }
            connected = true;
        }
    };

    public void setConnectionText(String text){
        connectionStatus.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
        if(gpsGoOn){
            discoverPeers();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    }

    private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(Socket skt){
            socket = skt;
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while(socket!=null){
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if(bytes>0){
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ServerClass extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;

        public ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress){
            hostAdd = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
            socket = new Socket();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd, 8888), 500);
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is the Error message I got after sending something.

--------- beginning of crash

```
2019-07-29 20:15:22.468 8068-8068/com.example.wificonnectiontry2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wificonnectiontry2, PID: 8068
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141)
        at com.example.wificonnectiontry2.MainActivity$SendReceive.write(MainActivity.java:320)
        at com.example.wificonnectiontry2.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:137)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) is raised when you are targeting Honeycomb or later, and you try to perform a network operation from the main UI thread. In older versions of Android, that was allowed (but not recommended). That is no longer the case in modern Android versions. You must move your network code into a separate thread or background task instead.